# While using boost, why should I take an error by parameter?

Tags: exception, boost, parameter-passing

I'm using boost, and I noticed it had overloaded many methods to use an error as parameter. If I know throw an error is a better approach, why should I use a parameter to know an exception?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some people have to program in an environment where, for some reason or other exceptions are not allowed.

There are also programming paradigms (such as network programming, for example) where errors are not "exceptional events", but rather things that are expected.

Some portions of boost (such as Boost.FileSystem, for example) offer both interfaces.
This lets the programmer choose how to handle errors.

For example (from Boost.FileSystem):

```
void copy(const path& from, const path& to);
void copy(const path& from, const path& to, system::error_code& ec);
```

If you prefer to handle errors by catching exceptions, then, by all means, do so.